# Java collector class usage

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, collectors

So I am trying to make sense of this but translating into simple statement. But I am having trouble doing so.

Var is a List class that holds bunch of values. I have a vague understanding of the code. This code is grabbing values that has not been assigned from assigned and inputting it into List of unassigned. But I don't understand how to translate it into simple statement to help me understand it more clearly.

```
List<Var> unassigned = assigned.stream()
                .filter((Var grabNear).(!grabNear.isAssigned()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This is what I have so far. Is this correct?

```
List<Var> unassigned = assigned;
Var grabNear;
            for(int i = 0; i < assigned.size(); ++i)
            {
                grabNear = assigned.get(i);
                if(!grabNear.isAssigned())
                {
                    unassigned.add(grabNear);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Collectors.toList()` creates a new `List`, so your code should look like this in order to be equivalent to the Java 8 code :

```
List<Var> unassigned = new ArrayList<>();
Var grabNear;
for(int i = 0; i < assigned.size(); ++i)
{
    grabNear = assigned.get(i);
    if(!grabNear.isAssigned())
    {
        unassigned.add(grabNear);
    }
}
```

P.S. the Java 8 code has an error in the filter method call. It should be :

```
.filter((Var grabNear) -> !grabNear.isAssigned())
```

or

```
.filter(grabNear -> !grabNear.isAssigned())
```

Comment: Thank you. That make more sense. Yeah I was trying something and forgot to remove the extra ()s.